# IE8 dropdown selections not clickable

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8

I am having an issue with IE8 whereby one of two drop down boxes is not working correctly. It works fine in Firefox, Chrome and Safari, as well as IE9+ but for some reason IE8 is not working.

Basically, the top drop down box lets you click and reveal the selections, but as soon as you move the mouse down to select an option, the drop down disappears. Sometimes you can be quick enough to select an option, or if you use the arrow keys you can select the options fine. The bottom box works perfectly with no issues, which is really weird.

Also, when I move the drop down boxes to the top of the form (above other input fields) it improves slightly by letting you double click the drop down and then selecting the options, but it is still not perfect.

**After testing further, it looks like the problem could be with these CSS toggle buttons I am using: http://ghinda.net/css-toggle-switch/ as these are also not displaying correctly (IE8 is ignoring all the styling).**

Sorry if I haven't been clear enough. The site is not yet live so I cant let you see it, but here is the code I am using.

```
<label class="control-label">Dropdown2</label>
<div class="controls">
  <select class="m-wrap" style="width: 100px; margin-left: 4px; margin-top: 4px;" id="option1" onChange="QuoteRefresh();" tabindex="1">
    <option value="">Select...</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="5">2</option>
    <option value="2">3</option>
    <option value="3">4</option>
    <option value="6">5</option>
    <option value="4">6</option>
  </select>
</div>
<label class="control-label">Dropdown 2</label>
<div class="controls">                                      
  <select class="m-wrap" style="width: 100px; margin-left: 4px; margin-top: 4px;"  id="option2" onChange="QuoteRefresh();" tabindex="1">
    <option value="">Select...</option>
    <option value="1000">1000</option>
    <option value="2000">2000</option>
    <option value="3000">3000</option>
    <option value="4000">4000</option>
    <option value="5000">5000</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

I have just removed the following code from my HTML and the problem has gone. This code relates to the toggle buttons mentioned above. However I need these toggle buttons to work with the drop downs.

```
  <div class="switch candy blue">
    <input id="op1" name="sat" type="radio">
    <label for="op1" onClick="">Yes</label>
    <input id="op2" name="sat" type="radio" checked>  
    <label for="op2" onClick="">No</label>
    <span class="slide-button"></span>
  </div>
```

Comment: what is the QuoteRefresh() function doing?

Comment: Hi Ollie, the QuoteRefresh() does some JQuery calculations, however I have since taken it out and the problem is still there, so It doesn't seem to be anything to do with that.

Comment: Says right on their page "Browsers without support for media-queries, such as IE8 and bellow, get standard form elements."

Comment: That explains why the toggle buttons aren't styled, however would that cause the drop downs to act the way they are too? Am I best looking for some different toggle buttons that work with IE8? Thanks for your help.

Comment: try taking the width off the select element IE8 doesn't always play fair with customising select menus with CSS.

Comment: Thanks for that Ollie but unfortunately that didn't work. I am looking at using some different toggle buttons. Hopefully that will solve the dropdown issue as well as sorting out the styling.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem in IE8 with select elements. I clicked, the options appeared, but then when I moved to select an option, they disappeared.

The problem for me was [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/). I thought I'd provide this answer only because CSS3 PIE is used quite commonly. In my case I was using it to round the corners of the select element in older browsers.

As soon as I removed the selector that I had added the CSS3 PIE "behavior" to, the problem went away. No rounded borders on select elements in IE8 anymore, but they're actually functional now.

Comment: Could you explain how you hunted this down to being a CSS3 PIE problem? I have exactly the same issue but I am not using CSS3 PIE, so I would like to know how to find out what it may be